# Markov-Property in Geometric Group Theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-process, geometric-group-theory

My question is about the following article:

https://arxiv.org/pdf/2002.10278.pdf

On page 34 the autors talk about the **Markov property** of hyperbolic groups. In particular , they say that the Cayleygraph of $\Gamma$ (which is a non-elementary hyperbolic group) has this Markov property but the Cayleygraphs of the supgroups of $\Gamma$ do not have it.

In the following article (2.2) I found a definition for Markov chains on groups:

https://arxiv.org/pdf/2111.09837.pdf

Unfortunatly I do not know how to transfer this definition to the context of the first article. Ans I also dont know why the Cayleygraph of $\Gamma$ (which is a non-elementary hyperbolic group) has this Markov property but the Cayleygraphs of the supgroups of $\Gamma$ do not have it.

Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: I have no further knowledge of these topics, but I would simply assume that the Markov property of groups has nothing to do with the Markov property of stochastic processes (as in your first mentioned paper they do not talk about stochastic processes). A quick google search gives me this Wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adian–Rabin_theorem which might be helpful for you.

Comment: As @stange says, these notions are completely unrelated. It is not even the same Markov. Markov chains are named for Andrey Markov (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrey_Markov) while Markov properties are named after his son Andrey Markov Jr (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrey_Markov_Jr.).

Comment: Actually, on further examination of the first paper you linked to, I have no idea what the authors mean by "*the* Markov property". I initially assumed they were referring to "*a* Markov property" as described at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adian%E2%80%93Rabin_theorem#Markov_property, but that does not seem to be the case.

Comment: Yes, this seem to be totally different things. Yeah, its really unclear what they exactly refer to. What they exactly mean by "the" Markov prperty...

Comment: Maybe I have an idea: On page 34/35 Fujiwara and Sela say that for a subgroup $H_{n_0}$ "we can not associate a finite state automata, that constructs a single geodesic from the identity to each element in the Cayleygraph of $H_{n_0}$, as we did in proposition 2.2." Maybe this is the Markov property they are talking about? Although I do not understand why one can construct such a automata for $\Gamma$, but not for the subgroups...